# Custom variantion wp7 slider

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

How would you guys go about creating a slider where the thumb stays centered, but the image or background of the slider slides with a slide gesture.

The only real example I could find is here, in the second screenshot:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/5ffe35e4-8e43-e011-854c-00237de2db9e

Basically the slider "thumb" would stay in place, but the numbers on the scale move with a finger swipe.

Just looking for some direction here on how you would approach this. What control would you recommend I start with? Or would it be easier to create a custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but a slider might be too hard because of the way it is constructed; the area/scale that you want to slide consists of two repeat buttons and those do not easily slide. So it might be best to NOT use the slider because the code of the Slider class expects these template parts to be present.

I'd try with plain, templated control. The thumb is pure decoration. I'd add the 'scale' in a scrollview without scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method when I get a chance. Do you think it would be simple to have the control "snap" to whole numbers? That is the piece I will most likely struggle with.

Comment: You will have to implement a method that moves/animates the scale. That animation will have to 'know' to what value it should slide so it would be quite fitting to calculate the snapping there.

Comment: I ended up playing around with the looping list and created a horizontal looping list for this control. Only really had to customize the appearance.

Comment: You mean the Teleric control? I didn't know you had it available.

Comment: Yep, although I think this would work also https://github.com/kvervo/HorizontalLoopingSelector